# Django not displayed data from db

Tags: python, django, django-templates, orm

[db image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5vjE.png)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5tTP.png)

```
#models.py
class Text(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, blank=False)
    text = models.TextField(blank=False)enter image description here
    public = models.BooleanField()


#views.py
def home(request):
    data = Text.objects.all()
    data = {
    'data': data
    }
    return render(request, 'app1/index.html', data)


#index.html
  <div class="container p-4 g-col-6 w-50  ">
      {% if data %}
        {% for i in data %}
        <div class="row bg-dark text-white  mt-3 rounded">
          <p class="p-1 text-info">{{ i.text }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
        <p>not data</p>
      {% endif %}enter image description hereenter image description here
  </div>'
```

I tried to output the manually recorded data several times - it was displayed perfectly, but when it comes to data from the model, nothing is displayed

I got:

```
    <QuerySet []>
    not data
```

when added data before if/else

```
<div class="container p-4 g-col-6 w-50  ">
    {{ data }}
      {% if data %}
        {% for i in data %}
        <div class="row bg-dark text-white  mt-3 rounded">
          <p class="p-1 text-info">{{ i.text }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
        <p>not data</p>
      {% endif %}
 </div>
```

**Solved**
In Datagrip, I have got two connections, hence two different tables with names 'Text' - done from alchemy, and 'app1_text' - empty.
I solved this just rename table name from alchemy and added data to django table.

Comment: Is it displays your `{% else %}` block or just empty? You should remove  if/else/endif blocks and use for/empty/endfor instead.

Comment: Can you place `{{ data }}` on your template before your if/else? And, let us know if your're seeing any data.

Comment: @MuhammadHammad
Yeah, updated

Comment: You checked you are using the same db?

Comment: I think yes, because in my Postgres appeared django special tables

Comment: @VANECK how did you upload data to db? Manually or through django console? What do you mean by "nothing is displayed"? What is nothing? `<p>not data</p>` or empty divs?

Comment: @Alex I found a block with conditions on the Internet , I thought it would help to find the error. I loaded the database using alchemy, I use datagrid for viewing. When migrating to postgres, the django table appeared.

Comment: @VANECK WDM run `python manage.py shell` and inside shell `from app1.models import Text` and then `print(Text.objects.all())`. I guess it would be empty.

Comment: @VANECK oh, didnt see images. You incorrectly uploaded data to db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your db is wrong.

Your **Text** table is not used in Django. Its just useless. There is app1_text which Django specially created for this model and it is empty.

Move all data from **Text** to **app1_text** but make sure thats everything fits Django model.

p.s.: all your custom django models will look in database like `AppName_ModelName`